# Error "Fatal SparkPostError: Exceed Sending Limit" when sandbox=true

Tags: sparkpost

I send the message via SparkPost API with option sandbox=true.
I get error "Fatal SparkPostError: Exceed Sending Limit"

I can't find description of the error in DOCs, Google or stackoverflow.

Anybody know what issues with sandbox of SparkPost? How much is limit for sandbox? When does it refresh?

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox options allows you to send using the @sparkpostbox.com domain. It is currently limited to 50 sends for the lifetime of the account. At this time you should have a verified sending domain to use going forward. If you are looking for information on testing using SparkPost, take a look at this support document: https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/2361300.