# Error when I send email SparkPost

Tags: sparkpost

First the "email send"  works fine but now It doesn't work anymore and when I print the error this is the text:

```
ERRORE {"name":"SparkPostError","errors":[{"message":"Message generation rejected","description":"Exceed Sending Limit (sandbox)","code":"1902"}],"statusCode":400}
```

Anyone can explein me how I'm wroing?

Comment: this does not concern apache-spark !

Answer (score 3):

This error says that you have reached the limit of messages sent from sparkpostbox.com and now must register your own sending domain.  [You can read about how to do that here](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/1933318-create-and-verify-sending-domains).

Each new SparkPost account may send a fixed number of messages addressed 'From:' sparkpostbox.com.  After that, the idea is that you register your own sending domain and send from that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox options allows you to send using the @sparkpostbox.com domain. It is currently limited to 50 sends for the lifetime of the account. At this time you should have a verified sending domain to use going forward. If you are looking for information on testing using SparkPost, take a look at this support document: https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/2361300

Source of the answer for your question is there: [Error "Fatal SparkPostError: Exceed Sending Limit" when sandbox=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542172/error-fatal-sparkposterror-exceed-sending-limit-when-sandbox-true)